# How to prevent a user from using "view source" to look at my php code and copy it?

Tags: php

How can I prevent a user from using "view source" to look at my php code and copy it?

thanks

Comment: They can't...PHP is a server side language. They can see the html output from the php file though.

Comment: Make it completely and utterly unreadable.

Comment: @Jesus: you do know that readability has nothing to do with copyability...

Comment: @Chris, yeah I know. Also PHP can't even be read with view source so it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Unless of course the PHP code happens to be a [quine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing))

Answer (score 1):

The php executable running on your server transforms the php input to produce HTML that is sent to the client.  The client does not see your php source.

Answer (score 1):

Users can't use "View Source" to see PHP code, only the generated HTML (assuming that's what you're creating.)

When a user requests a PHP page, it is run by the PHP handler on your server, and the output (which won't contain any code) is sent back to the user.

Answer (score 1):

That's easy.  You don't have to do anything.  PHP code is not visible to the user, only the HTML code that the PHP produces.

Answer (score 1):

If you are serving your PHP file through a typical LAMP/WAMP setup, don't worry at all. BTW, this reminds me a similar question by a team of talented .NET developers. They were concerned about Open Source nature of PHP and if some one will be able to see their PHP code. And if your server can not serve PHP file but you still serve PHP files, yes then they will see all your secret source code. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this yourself? You can't see php code using "view source". Now if your *server* is misconfigured, then yes it may accidentally send your php code as plain text. But that's not a client problem.

Done and done.

Answer (score 1):

That's a false proposition. How do you *enable* a user to do that?

PHP is parsed on the server and never reaches the client. A user cannot simply hit *View Source* to see your server-side PHP code. If he can, your server is broken.

Answer (score 0):

If your site is working correctly, they won't see any of your PHP code, just the resulting HTML/Javascript whatever that it is outputing.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is server side language .. viewing source is only HTML  and/or javascript .. But it is possible to hide even html but that's may not work always // since many debugger tools are available like firebug which tracks everything .

php scripts can be view in browser only when  apache or iis or any server stops working which seems like very rare case .. so stop bothering . :)

Answer (score 0):

don't rename php file into .inc .script or .something else but .php

because web server will treat them in the same way as .txt

to be clear...they will show directly what's in there.